Could the coredump in a process using libssh be due to a libssh Issue?
I have a situation where a single C++ process can run multiple SSH servers and SSH clients concurrently. Each SSH server and client runs in a separate thread, with each thread having its own ssh_session object, ensuring that the sessions are not shared between threads.
I'm currently using libssh 0.10.5.
BackTrace
#0 0x00007f42de961205 in std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned long) () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#1 0x00000000004baa5c in CServerHandle::run_auth_gssapi_mic(ssh_session_struct*, char const*, char const*) ()
#2 0x00000000004bfc91 in CServerHandle::cb_auth_gssapi_mic(ssh_session_struct*, char const*, char const*, void*) ()
#3 0x0000000000512156 in ssh_client_connection_callback ()
#4 0x0000000000515d36 in ssh_packet_kexinit ()
#5 0x0000000000527efa in ssh_packet_process ()
#6 0x00000000005278e1 in ssh_packet_socket_callback ()
#7 0x00000000005279be in ssh_packet_socket_callback ()
#8 0x00000000005279be in ssh_packet_socket_callback ()
#9 0x00000000005279be in ssh_packet_socket_callback ()
#10 0x00000000005279be in ssh_packet_socket_callback ()
#11 0x00000000005279be in ssh_packet_socket_callback ()
#12 0x00000000005279be in ssh_packet_socket_callback ()
#13 0x00000000005279be in ssh_packet_socket_callback ()
#14 0x00000000005279be in ssh_packet_socket_callback ()
#15 0x00000000005279be in ssh_packet_socket_callback ()
#16 0x00000000005279be in ssh_packet_socket_callback ()
#17 0x00000000005279be in ssh_packet_socket_callback ()
#18 0x0000000000534d99 in ssh_socket_pollcallback ()
#19 0x0000000000532030 in ssh_poll_ctx_dopoll ()
#20 0x00000000005324f2 in ssh_event_dopoll ()
#21 0x000000000048bdde in CSession::tryEventPoll() ()
#22 0x00000000004aad78 in CHandle::handleSession(std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int> >&) ()
#23 0x00000000004a5a2a in CClientHandle::service() ()
#24 0x00000000004e0a52 in CThread::callService(void*) ()
#25 0x00007f42defcfea5 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#26 0x00007f42de0bb8dd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Function where the coredump occurred
int CServerHandle::run_auth_gssapi_mic(ssh_session session, const char *user, const char *principal) {
    LOG("[AUTH > GSSAPI-MIC] %s. (user)%s, (principal)%s",
            m_info.getSummary().c_str(),
            user, principal);

    m_account = (NULL != user) ? user : ""; // std::string m_account

    int ret = SSH_AUTH_ERROR;

    LOG("[AUTH > GSSAPI-MIC] %s. [RET]%d",
            m_info.getSummary().c_str(),
            ret);

    return ret;
}

Related Functions
class CServerHandle : public CHandle {
public:
    CServerHandle() : CHandle() {
        m_session.setIsServer(true);

        ::memset(&m_serverCallbacks, 0x00, sizeof(m_serverCallbacks));
        m_serverCallbacks.userdata = this;
        m_serverCallbacks.service_request_function = cb_service_request;
        m_serverCallbacks.channel_open_request_session_function = cb_channel_open;
        m_serverCallbacks.auth_none_function = cb_auth_none;
        m_serverCallbacks.auth_password_function = cb_auth_password;
        m_serverCallbacks.auth_pubkey_function = cb_auth_public;
        m_serverCallbacks.auth_gssapi_mic_function = cb_auth_gssapi_mic;
        m_serverCallbacks.gssapi_select_oid_function = cb_gssapi_select_oid;
        m_serverCallbacks.gssapi_accept_sec_ctx_function = cb_gssapi_accept_sec_ctx;
        m_serverCallbacks.gssapi_verify_mic_function = cb_gssapi_verify_mic;
        ssh_callbacks_init(&m_serverCallbacks);
    }

    static inline int cb_auth_gssapi_mic(ssh_session session, const char *user, const char *principal, void *userdata) {
        return ((CServerHandle *)userdata)->run_auth_gssapi_mic(session, user, principal);
    }

    ...

private:
    struct ssh_server_callbacks_struct m_serverCallbacks;
}

class CHandler {
    ...

private:
    CSession m_session;
    std::string m_account;                              
}

The CSession class contains an ssh_session object as a member. In the CServerHandler class, during the accept client, the ssh_server_callbacks_struct is passed as an argument, and ssh_set_server_callbacks() is used to set callbacks for each ssh_session object.
Why I suspect this is a libssh issue:

As you can see from the backtrace, I don't see any obvious reason in the problematic function that would lead to a core dump. The SSH server does not support GSSAPI authentication, so there's nothing special being handled there. If the issue occurs when assigning the user to m_account, it seems like libssh might be passing incorrect memory to the callback function.

run_auth_gssapi_mic() is registered as a server callback according to the call stack. It is not registered on the client side, meaning it should not be used there. However, the backtrace shows that the callback function is somehow being invoked starting from the SSH client handler(CClientHandle), through the libssh poll process, and eventually reaching the server callback function(cb_auth_gssapi_mic()).

The SSH client handler had already successfully connected to the server (ssh_connect() had succeeded). Thus, it's odd that the GSSAPI-related function would be called through the libssh poll process.


While I have inferred these possibilities, I haven't yet been able to reproduce the issue reliably.
Questions:

Am I potentially misusing libssh in some way?
Has anyone experienced a similar issue?
Should this be considered a libssh bug?
Could this be a memory-related bug occurring due to the way the OS interacts with the library?

What did you try?
I reviewed the backtrace and the related code functions to understand where the issue might be originating. I suspect the issue could be related to how libssh handles memory or callback functions. I have tried analyzing the flow of execution and the callbacks being registered but haven't found a definitive cause yet.
What were you expecting?
I expected that the SSH client and server would operate independently within their respective threads without causing a core dump.

You need to use a debugger to see whether the user is indeed valid. It's possible that your program is corrupting libssh. Try running with a memory validation tool like valgrind.

Does each thread get its own CServerHandle object?  If a single m_account were being using touched in multiple threads, that would be bad.  There's no locking.

Please show a [mre]

@RaymondChen
The coredump occurs in a different environment and does not happen consistently. In my own environment, it hasn’t occurred at all. As a result, I’m currently unable to reproduce the issue and therefore haven’t been able to use a debugger to inspect the user variable.

@TimRoberts Each thread operating as an SSH server has its own CServerHandler instance. Consequently, each CServerHandler has its own m_account, and it is not shared between threads.

@PasserBy Thank you. I’m continuing to try to reproduce the issue. If I find any additional information, I’ll update the post.

And are you guaranteed that those callbacks are serialized?  It would only take a few moments to put a mutex in there as an experiment.

You can look at the value of user from the core dump.

@TimRoberts
Are you asking if the same callback function might be accessed concurrently in a multi-threaded environment?
I haven't tested the scenario where the client handler transitions to the server handler as seen in the backtrace, but the callbacks registered for each server handler (thread) are separate from each other, so even with a mutex, they would still be accessed simultaneously.

@RaymondChen The process in the environment where the issue is occurring was not built with the -g option. It may be challenging to patch it with a version built with -g, but I will need to check if that's possible.

You evidently have enough symbols that you can see CServerHandle::run_auth_gssapi_mic, so check the user parameter there. In the future, you can save the debug information in a separate file that you don't ship to the customer but retain privately for later debugging.

Did you find out what caused the crash ?
What encryption backend are you using ? MBedTLS must be compiled with explicit support for multithreading whereas OpenSSL takes care of locking automatically (since version 1.1.1).
